# Failed to resolve component: ejs-multiselect with VueJs, import error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i'm trying to integrate the CheckBox in Vue MultiSelect component from here: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/multi-select/checkbox/#checkbox
into my project

the code looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="category-definition-details">
    <form class="create-form">
      ...
      <div id='container' style="margin:15px auto 0; width:250px;">
        <ejs-multiselect id='multiselect' :dataSource='sportsData' placeholder="Find a game" mode="CheckBox" :fields='fields'></ejs-multiselect>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
...
import { MultiSelectPlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";
import { MultiSelect, CheckBoxSelection } from '@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns';
MultiSelect.Inject(CheckBoxSelection);
@Options({
components: { MultiSelectPlugin },
})

export default class myClass extends Vue {
data (){
return {
sportsData: [
{ Id: 'game1', Game: 'Badminton' },
{ Id: 'game2', Game: 'Football' },
{ Id: 'game3', Game: 'Tennis' },
{ Id: 'game4', Game: 'Golf' },
{ Id: 'game5', Game: 'Cricket' },
{ Id: 'game6', Game: 'Handball' },
{ Id: 'game7', Game: 'Karate' },
{ Id: 'game8', Game: 'Fencing' },
{ Id: 'game9', Game: 'Boxing' }
],
fields : { text: 'Game', value: 'Id' }
}
}
}
</script>
```

i get the following warning
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: ejs-multiselect
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions...

i tried to add the line Vue.use(MultiSelectPlugin);
but it doesn't work since i already imported Vue from vue-class-component

i also tries to add the following lines
import * as _vue from 'vue';
_vue.use(MultiSelectPlugin);
but i get the error Property 'use' does not exist on type import...

someone knows what is the correct way to import this module?

Answer (score 0):

I have just added all the relevant code. `onSelect` method will help to push your data to `selectedSports`. `selectedSports` will have your selected values.

**Template Code:** Put it in your template under some div

```js
        <ejs-multiselect
              id="multiselect"
              :dataSource="sportsData"
              :select="onSelect"
        ></ejs-multiselect>
```

**Script Code:** Put it in your script

```js
import { MultiSelectComponent  } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";

// add ejs-multiselect where you have defined your components
export default defineComponent({
    // removed extra code 
    components: {
        "ejs-multiselect": MultiSelectComponent    
    },
    data() {
      return {
        sportsData: [
           "Cricket",
           "Badminton",
           "Golf",
           "Boxing",
        ],
        selectedSports: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
       onSelect(event) {
           this.selectedSports.push(event.itemData)
       }
    }
})
```

**It will be shown like this:**

[image]